# How to solve for the optimal portfolio weight with target variance?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, markowitz

I'm confused a bit with the following problem:
As far as i understand, the following problem where

$$\min_{w} \omega^{T}\Sigma\omega$$
$$\textrm{s.t.}\hspace{0.5cm} \omega^{T}\mu=E$$
$$ \omega^{T}\textbf{1}=1 $$

yields the analytical solution
$$w^{*}=\frac{\Sigma^{-1}\mu}{1'\Sigma^{-1}\mu} $$
where $w$ represents the vector of optimal portfolio weights.

The derivation of the former appears relatively easy as the constraint in the maximization problem is linear thus i can solve the linear system of equations for the lagrange multipliers, plug them back into my first FOC and solve for the weights vector.

The derivation of the analytical form of the equivalent dual representation where i maximize the portfolio return for a given level of portfolio volatility of the form:
$$\max_{w} \omega^{T}\mu$$
$$\textrm{s.t.}\hspace{0.5cm} \omega^{T}\Sigma\omega=\sigma^2$$
$$ \omega^{T}\textbf{1}=1 $$
is not so straight forward to me as i'm stuggeling at the point where i try to solve for the lagrange multipliers given the FOC for the portfolio weights:
$$\frac{d{L(\dots)}}{d{\omega}}=\mu-2\lambda_{1}\Sigma\omega-\lambda_{2}\textbf{1}=0$$
$$\frac{d{L(\dots)}}{d{\lambda_{1}}}=\sigma^{2}-\omega^{T}\Sigma\omega=0$$
$$\frac{d{L(\dots)}}{d{\lambda_{2}}}=1-\omega^{T}\textbf{1}=0$$

Here, $\mu$ is the vector of expected returns, $\omega$ the vector of asset weights, $\Sigma$ the covariance matrix, $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$ the lagrange multipliers for constraints 1 and 2 and $\sigma^2$ is my target variance.

The problem here (at least for me) is that the first derivative for the lagrange multiplier of the variance constraint  includes two weight-vectors and thus yields a quadratic expression, for which i can't easily solve the second FOC for the needed lagrange multipliers.. and i'm not sure whether i'm on the right track and if yes, how to solve for the analytical expression of $\omega$.

My question: If i want to maximize expected return given my portfolio variance equals some  target variance, how does my solution $w$ change and how to explicitly derive this step-by-step (or where can i find some paper where this derivation has been made)?

EDIT: I spent a few hours yesterday night and came up with the closed form for $\omega$ ignoring the sum of weights equal 100% constraint:

In detail:
$$\max_{w} \omega^{T}\mu$$
$$\textrm{s.t.}\hspace{0.5cm} \omega^{T}\Sigma\omega=\sigma^2$$

The Lagrangean is:
$$L(\dots)=\omega^{T}\mu+\lambda(\sigma^{2}-\omega^{T}\Sigma\omega)$$

for which the FOCs are:
$$\frac{dL(\dots)}{d\omega}=\mu-2\lambda\Sigma\omega=0$$
$$\frac{dL(\dots)}{d\lambda}=\sigma^{2}-\omega^{T}\Sigma\omega=0$$

such that
$$(\frac{1}{2\lambda}\Sigma^{-1}\mu)\Sigma(\frac{1}{2\lambda}\Sigma^{-1}\mu)=\sigma^2$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{4\lambda^2}\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu=\sigma^2$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{2\sigma}\sqrt{\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu}=\lambda$$

Pugging back into the first FOC:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2\sigma}\sqrt{\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu}})\Sigma^{-1}\mu=\omega$$
and thus:
$$\omega^{*}=\frac{\sigma\Sigma^{-1}\mu}{\sqrt{\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu}}$$

For the problem with the sum-of-weights constraint the problem is:
$$\max_{w} \omega^{T}\mu$$
$$\textrm{s.t.}\hspace{0.5cm} \omega^{T}\Sigma\omega=\sigma^2$$
$$ \omega^{T}\textbf{1}=1 $$

The Lagrangean reads as:
$$L(\dots)=\omega^{T}\mu+\lambda_{1}(1-\omega^{T}\textbf{1})+\lambda_{2}(\sigma^{2}-\omega^{T}\Sigma\omega)$$

The FOCs are:
$$\frac{dL(\dots)}{d\omega}=\mu--\lambda_{1}\textbf{1}-2\lambda_{2}\Sigma\omega=0$$
$$\frac{dL(\dots)}{d\lambda_1}=1-\omega^{T}\textbf{1}=0$$
$$\frac{dL(\dots)}{d\lambda_1}=\sigma^{2}-\omega^{T}\Sigma\omega=0$$

From the first FOC we get:

$$\omega =\dfrac{1}{2\lambda_1} \Sigma^{-1} ( \mu - \lambda_2 \mathbf{1}) $$

By multiplying this a) with $\Sigma$ and a second time b) with $\textbf{1}$ and using the second and third FOCs:

$$\frac{1}{(2\lambda_1)^2}(\mu -\lambda_2\textbf{1} )^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-\lambda_2 \textbf{1})=\sigma^2$$
$$\Rightarrow\omega^{T}\mu=\lambda_{1}+2\lambda_{2}\sigma^2$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2\lambda_1}\mathbf{1}^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(\mu -\lambda_2\textbf{1} )=1 $$
$$\Rightarrow\omega^{T}\mu=\frac{1}{2\lambda_1}(\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu-\lambda_{1}\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{1})$$

Notation from here onwards:
$$A=\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu$$
$$B=\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{1}$$
$$C=\textbf{1}^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{1}$$

Combining the two equations by  $\omega^{T}\mu$ and eliminating $(2\lambda_1)$:
$$\lambda_{1}+2\lambda_{2}\sigma^2=\frac{1}{2\lambda_{2}}(A-\lambda_{1})$$

Now using $\omega$ from the first FOC again and multiply both sides with $\textbf{1}$ we get:
$$B-\lambda_{1}C=2\lambda_{2}$$

We can substitute this now for $2\lambda_{2}$ in the equation above and get the quadratic expression:
$$\lambda_{1}^{2}(C^{2}\sigma^{2}-C)+\lambda_{1}(2B-BC\sigma^2)+(B^{2}\sigma^{2}-A)=0$$

for which we get the messy solution(s):
$$\lambda_{1}^{*}=\frac{-(2B-BC\sigma^2)\pm\sqrt{B^{2}(4-3C^{2}\sigma^{4})-AC}}{2C(C\sigma^{2}-1)}$$

We then solve for $\lambda_{1}$, and $\omega$:

$$\lambda_{1}^{*}=B-\frac{-(2B-BC\sigma^2)\pm\sqrt{B^{2}(4-3C^{2}\sigma^{4})-AC}}{4C\sigma^{2}-4}$$

and finally:
$$\omega^{*}=\frac{1}{\frac{-(2B-BC\sigma^2)\pm\sqrt{B^{2}(4-3C^{2}\sigma^{4})-AC}}{2C\sigma^{2}-2}}(\Sigma^{-1}\mu-(\frac{-(2B-BC\sigma^2)\pm\sqrt{B^{2}(4-3C^{2}\sigma^{4})-AC}}{4C\sigma^{2}-4})\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{1})$$

My questions now:
Is this expression correct?
For which values is the expression under the square root positive?
Is there a mathematical reasoning, which $\lambda_{2}^{*}$ to use (w.r.t. the $\pm$-sign)?

Thank you again for your help :-)
Yours
Thomas

Comment: @nbbo2 thanks for your comment. I thought I wrote that.. 

Comment: Section 1.2 of this is related to your question and I think answers it but I didn't go over it carefully. http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/FoundationsFE/MeanVariance-CAPM.pdf

Comment: @markleeds thanks for the link and the comment. I'm not sure but I guess I'm not clear in my question. I will rewrite it tomorrow, hopefully it becomes a bit clearer what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: @T123: I think I understand your question now but I read it incorrectly the first time which caused me to find something not relevant. My mistake.

Comment: Your expression is correct, see equation 2.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3396.pdf

Comment: @Hans-PeterSchrei Thanks for the confirmation and thank you for the paper!

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to updated question:**

The new expression for $\omega^*$ is also not correct. To see why let:

$$
\begin{split}
\mu &:= \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix} = \textbf{1} \\
\Sigma &:= \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{split}
$$

In this case,

$$
\Sigma^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So

$$
A = B = C = \textbf{1}^T \Sigma^{-1}\textbf{1} = 1
$$

This lets us simplify $\omega^*$ to:

$$
\omega^* = \frac{2\sigma^2 - 2}{\sigma^2 - 2 \pm \sqrt{3 - 3\sigma^4}} \left(1 + \frac{2 - \sigma^2 \pm \sqrt{3 - 3\sigma^4}}{4\sigma^2-4} \right)\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{1}
$$

Let:

$$
\alpha(\sigma) := \frac{2\sigma^2 - 2}{\sigma^2 - 2 \pm \sqrt{3 - 3\sigma^4}} \left(1 + \frac{2 - \sigma^2 \pm \sqrt{3 - 3\sigma^4}}{4\sigma^2-4} \right)
$$

Then

$$
\omega^* = \alpha(\sigma)\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{1}
$$

Since $\left(\omega^*\right)^T\textbf{1} = 1$,

$$
\begin{split}
& \left(\alpha(\sigma)\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{1}\right)^T\textbf{1} = 1 \\
\Rightarrow \quad& \alpha(\sigma)\textbf{1}^T\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{1} = 1 \\
\Rightarrow \quad& \alpha(\sigma) = 1 \\
\end{split}
$$

So the constraint $\left(\omega^*\right)^T\textbf{1} = 1$ is voilated for any $\sigma$ that's not a zero of the equation $\alpha(\sigma) - 1$.

Note, while there may be a closed-form solution to this problem, it's not clear that there is, because of the nonlinear constraint this problem formulation introduces. If you can't find a closed-form solution, you may need to resort to a numerical solution using a nonlinear programming method, or reformulate the problem, like the original quadratic programming problem you referenced, where you minimize the variance rather than maximize the expected return.

**Answer to original question:**

(The original question asked if

$$\omega^* = \frac{\sigma\Sigma^{-1}\mu}{\sqrt{\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu}}$$

was a solution the same problem. My answer to that previous question is below, in case it helps anyone else.)

This expression is not correct. To see why, consider this example. Let:

$$
\begin{split}
\mu &:= \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix} = \textbf{1} \\
\Sigma &:= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = I \\
\end{split}
$$

Note that
$$
\Sigma^{-1}\mu = I^{-1}\textbf{1} = I \textbf{1} = \textbf{1}
$$

So
$$
\begin{split}
\omega^* &= \frac{\sigma\Sigma^{-1}\mu}{\sqrt{\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu}} \\
 &= \frac{\sigma\textbf{1}}{\sqrt{\mu^T\textbf{1}}} \\
&= \frac{\sigma\textbf{1}}{\sqrt{\textbf{1}^T\textbf{1}}} \\
&= \frac{\sigma\textbf{1}}{\sqrt{2}} \\
&= \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2}} \textbf{1}
\end{split}
$$

But then:

$$
\begin{split}
1−(\omega^*)^T\textbf{1} &= 1 - \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2}} \textbf{1}^T\textbf{1} \\
&= 1 - \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2}} 2\\
&= 1 - \frac{2\sigma}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{split}
$$

For any $\sigma \neq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$:

$$
1−(\omega^*)^T\textbf{1} \neq 0
$$

So the third Lagrangian condition is not satisfied in general.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it misses the full investment constraint. I already have a solution for both constraints and will post an update later!.. And there is a sigma missing in your optimal omega..

Comment: Good catch. I corrected this.

Comment: Hi @Adam I've updated my question. Would you mind posting your current answer into a comment so we don't lose it?

Comment: I tried to answer your new question, and I kept the answer to your question around as an addendum, in case it helps someone else. (I thought putting it in a comment would make it quite hard to read!)

Comment: thank you again for your answer, I really appreciate it. I also found that this equation doesn't give me a sum of weights that are equal to one. I'm sure I made a mistake somewhere. Do you have an idea where I need to correct it?

Comment: I don't want to say your approach is "wrong", but I will say it's not the approach I'd take. You're looking for a closed-form solution to the optimization problem, but I'm not sure you're going to be able to find a closed-form solution. You might, and if you do, that's an interesting result. If you just want a numerical answer though, I think a numerical method should work, because unless I'm missing something, you're maximizing an affine function on a convex set, which is equivalent to minimizing (-1) times your affine function on the same set, so numerical methods should work well.

Comment: Yes, thank you again for your thoughts. I already have a numerical solution in place, however, I'm still interested in a closed Form solution as I need to run approx 20 Mio optimizations and that will take a while. I need to get a target vola as that's what my client required, not a target return ( that's why I'm not minimizing vola as suggested above).

Comment: The closed form solution might not speed things up, assuming it requires matrix inversion. That said, even if it doesn’t speed things up, it’s useful to have, since it gives you a good way to validate your other approach. Good luck! (Please post back if you do find a solution.)